# Saving uploaded files in a specific folder in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP, is it possible to save uploaded files in respective user directories `user_id_directory`?

If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

```
$userid = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));

$folder = new Folder (WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'user' . DS . $userid['User']['id'], true);
```

This example creates a folder in webroot/img/user/ based on logged in User. You can replace ['id'] with ['username'] , etc.